# Send Workflow Email from Executing User Dynamics CRM

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I have created a button on Account Homepage which has a functionality to trigger workflow after a specified record is selected and the button is clicked.
I want to send email on behalf of the user who is initiating the workflow but I am a little bit confused about what to put in From field of the email workflow.

Any kind of help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the From-field blank in your Send Email-step in an on-demand workflow. The email will then be sent from the user triggering the workflow.

Comment: The "on-demand" piece of this answer is vital.  If the button triggers a field change which triggers the workflow, then the workflow will not be run on-demand, and the owner of the workflow will be the sender of the email; whereas if the button calls the workflow directly, it will be on-demand and the email will be sent by the user who clicked the button.

Comment: Hi henrik
i have already tried what you just said but whenever i left the From field blank the email is not sent.